# Multivariate Non-linear minimization in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I need to minimize the objective function shown below, the variables in green boxes will be introduced to the formula and the variables in red boxes needed to be optimized and there will be a starting value for each. as of yet the optimization is not constrained. I put the formula here not to wait for a code but for the responses to have an idea about the function. What I've done so far: I searched the threads, I've tried the `nlm` command on a toy function:

```
fn =function(x,a) {sum(100*a+(2*x^2+5*x-7))}
nlm(fn , a<-c(10),x<- c(100), hessian=TRUE)
```

but I couldn't get the value for the optimum (a) and I doubt that I've some errors in the formula, I am using this formula as a starting point to tackle the formula below. What I am looking for is can any one point me to the suitable function in R that I will start from.

[image: The Obj. Function]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally calling R functions with assignment operators in the argument list will produce failure. This is one area where `<-` is NOT the same as `=`. I wouldn't have thought this would work :

```
 nlm(fn , a =c(10), x = c(100), hessian=TRUE)  # and it didn't
```

The error message is informative, telling you there is a missing parameter p:

```
> fn =function(x,p) {sum(100*p[1]+(2*x^2+5*x-7))}
> nlm(fn , p=c(10),x = c(100), hessian=TRUE)
$minimum
[1] -4988507

$estimate
[1] -50090

$gradient
[1] 100

$hessian
     [,1]
[1,]    0

$code
[1] 5

$iterations
[1] 6
```

Comment: 1- What's in case if I want to optimize the value of p as well?              2-can I use the nlm for the function that I've listed above., Thanks

Comment: `p` was only the starting value of the parameter(s). It could have been a vector of values if the function accepted more arguments.  You should try reading through the help page for `nlm` again and working with all the examples.

Comment: Does that mean the (no. of parameters in the functions)=(length(p))?

Comment: Right. And the typical way to represent them in the function is p[1],p[2],...,p[n]. As to your second question I really do not know. There are quite a few undefined functions and values in there. You might want to look at the 'optimx' package where quite a few optimizers have been assembled under one roof.

Comment: one more question, for the function above, is nlm the right way to start from ?

Answer (score 1):

I actually recommend not putting extra parameters that are not needed to optimize into your function. It's easier to mess up if you have complicated name for parameters.

I would warp your function like this:

```
fn = function(x,a) {sum(100*a+(2*x^2+5*x-7))}
f = function(x) {fn(x, 100)}
nlm(f, 10, hessian=TRUE)
```